# Error: Objects are not valid as a React child when trying to map a nested array for a table component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, frontend, syntax-error

My code has been working fine so far. Until I had to modify the data file and create a nested array inside it. I am getting the **Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {one, B, C, D, E, G, H, I, L, M, N, P, Q, R, S}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.**

Below is my Table Component

```
import React from "react";
import tableData from "./tableData1.js";

const TableComponent = ({ data }) => {
let headings = Object.keys(data[0]);
  return (
    <table className="table table-dark table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="16">Dimensions in mm</th>
        </tr>
        <tr scope="col">
          <th>Series</th>
          {headings.map((heading) => (
            <th>{heading}</th>
          ))}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {data.map((item) => (
          <tr scope="col">
            <th scope="row">Series No.</th>
            {headings.map((heading) => (
              <td>{item[heading]}</td>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

const TableGenerator = ( {targetID} ) => {
  const filteredData = tableData.filter(item => item.id == targetID ).map(item => item.value);
  return <TableComponent data={filteredData} />;
};

export default TableGenerator;
```

And here is the Data File currently using only some mock data for testing.

```
const tableData1 = [
  {
    id: 1,
    value: [
      {
        one: "Value",
        B: "Value",
        C: "Value",
        D: "Male",
        E: "Value",
        G: "Value",
        H: "Value",
        I: "Value",
        L: "Value",
        M: "Value",
        N: "Value",
        P: "Value",
        Q: "Value",
        R: "Value",
        S: "Value",
      },
      {
        one: "Value",
        B: "Value",
        C: "Value",
        D: "Male",
        E: "Value",
        G: "Value",
        H: "Value",
        I: "Value",
        L: "Value",
        M: "Value",
        N: "Value",
        P: "Value",
        Q: "Value",
        R: "Value",
        S: "Value",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    value: [
      {
        two: "Value",
        B: "Value",
        C: "Value",
        D: "Male",
        E: "Value",
        G: "Value",
        H: "Value",
        I: "Value",
        L: "Value",
        M: "Value",
        N: "Value",
        P: "Value",
        Q: "Value",
        R: "Value",
        S: "Value",
      },
      {
        two: "Value",
        B: "Value",
        C: "Value",
        D: "Male",
        E: "Value",
        G: "Value",
        H: "Value",
        I: "Value",
        L: "Value",
        M: "Value",
        N: "Value",
        P: "Value",
        Q: "Value",
        R: "Value",
        S: "Value",
      },
    ],
  }
]
```

Previously I had it in the format below:

```
const tableData1 = [
  {
    id: 1,
    value:
      {
        one: "Value",
        B: "Value",
        C: "Value",
        D: "Male",
        E: "Value",
        G: "Value",
        H: "Value",
        I: "Value",
        L: "Value",
        M: "Value",
        N: "Value",
        P: "Value",
        Q: "Value",
        R: "Value",
        S: "Value",
      }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    value:
      {
        two: "Value",
        B: "Value",
        C: "Value",
        D: "Male",
        E: "Value",
        G: "Value",
        H: "Value",
        I: "Value",
        L: "Value",
        M: "Value",
        N: "Value",
        P: "Value",
        Q: "Value",
        R: "Value",
        S: "Value",
      }
  }
]
```

I'm guessing I have to map it differently or something along those lines, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it no matter where I look. Anyone able to help out on this?

Comment: I'm lost on which type of that should work, the mock or the previous data?

Comment: const filteredData = tableData.filter(item => item.id == targetID ).map(item => item.value);  in the map method each item is: [
      {
        one: "Value",
        B: "Value",
        C: "Value",
        D: "Male",
...},      {
        one: "Value",
        B: "Value",
        C: "Value",
        D: "Male",
...}]


so you need another map to each of this element
and why you may need duplicate object?

Comment: Seen as value as gone from been a singleton object, into an array of objects.  Don't you now want to be rendering multiple TableComponent?..  As TableComponent is expecting an object, not an array..

Comment: @Vencovsky the mock data i shared first is where i need it to work as it works already for the second.

Comment: @Ebay what i am basically trying to achieve is the Object.keys is meant to get me all the headings from each of the objects inside the value array and the rest of the code is meant to generate rows under those headings based on the values of those headings(properties), if that makes any sense.

Comment: Instead of filter, I personally would use find, using `data[0]` just feels wrong to me, also your value subArray, are you meant to be finding in there as well?,.. If not are you always assuming the first array element is where your getting the headings from, or do you want to render both??.  You have obviously converted value into an array, it must have been for some reason..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since in your new structure `value` is itself an array, actually you have a nested array, you can update your `filterData` like this:

```
const filteredData = tableData.filter(item => item.id == targetID).reduce((acc, item)=>{
  acc = [...acc, ...item.value]
  return acc;
} , []);
```

Comment: this did it! I was a little confused on how to access that data properly and this works just fine. previous answer worked too btw. thank you!